# java.lang.ClassCastException when I use Drools query

Tags: java, drools, classcastexception

My exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
ir.rashasoft.bss.rate.domain.action.impl.AppliedPartyBillingRate cannot be cast to ir.rashasoft.bss.rate.domain.action.impl.AppliedPartyBillingRate
```

I use this code in my code:

query "Get All AppliedPartyBillingRate"
     $apbr: AppliedPartyBillingRate()
     end;

and when i want use that for

```
  AppliedPartyBillingRate billingRate = null;
  billingRate = (AppliedPartyBillingRate) resultsRow.get("$apbr");
```

I get that exception. Please direct me.

Comment: It appears to me that you have 2 different definitions of `ir.rashasoft.bss.rate.domain.action.impl.AppliedPartyBillingRate` in your classpath. The Drools engine and your app are using different versions.
How are you interacting with the KIE Session? Are you creating the Kie Base in your own app? Or are you interacting with it through a service?

Comment: Thanks you for your attention.
I create that in my own app. What is the difference between them ?

Comment: Having different versions of the same library when you have multiple applications is sometimes more difficult to solve our validate (specially if one of the apps is a canned app). If your project is a maven project, try to do a `mvn dependency:tree` to check that you don't have different versions of the jar containing the conflicting class.